# non duplicate multiple SQL records I can't get rid of

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot, ssms

I'm trying to generate a report that will show which users are restricted to a certain facilities. The base code I'm using is:

```
 `SELECT DISTINCT ppp.DeptID,
        mis.UserID,
        mis.[Name],
        CASE 
            WHEN mis.ProviderID IS NULL
                THEN 'No'
            ELSE 'YES'
            END AS 'IsProv',
        CASE 
            WHEN af.FacilityID = 'PSY'
                THEN 'Restricted'
            ELSE 'Not Restricted'
            END AS 'SignOnFacility',
        CASE 
            WHEN fr.FacilitiesRestrictedID = 'PSY'
                THEN 'Restricted'
            ELSE 'Not Restricted'
            END AS 'FacilityToRestrict',
        mis.Active
    FROM DMisUsers mis
    LEFT JOIN DMisUserRestrictedAdmMriFac fr
        ON mis.UserID = fr.UserID
            AND mis.SourceID = fr.SourceID
    LEFT JOIN DMisUserAdmMriFacility af
        ON af.UserID = mis.UserID
    INNER JOIN PpEmployees pe
        ON mis.SourceID = pe.SourceID
            AND mis.UserID = pe.UserID
    INNER JOIN PpPayrollPosition ppp
        ON ppp.EmployeeID = pe.EmployeeID
            AND pe.SourceID = ppp.SourceID
    WHERE mis.SourceID = 'STP'
        AND mis.Active = 'Y'`
```

Which produces the following result set which is bringing in one row for each 'facility' column.

```
 | DeptID | UserID  |IsProv| SignOnFacility | FacilityToRestrict | Active|
 |01.9030 | PPaul   |   No | Not Restricted | Not Restricted     | Y     |
 |01.9030 | PPaul   |   No | Not Restricted | Restricted         | Y     |
```

What I'm trying to do is to get a single row like :

```
 | DeptID | UserID  |IsProv| SignOnFacility | FacilityToRestrict | Active|
 |01.9030 | PPaul   |   No | Not Restricted | Restricted         | Y     |
```

I've tried CTE's, pivots using `Row_Number()` to get around aggregation, and several other methods. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What determines which row to keep/remove?

Comment: The problem is with the FacilityToRestrict. If you got rid of that column, your "DISTINCT" would take care of the rest. So the question is, why does FacilityToRestrict come back with different values for the same user?

Comment: Can you please provide the output for the following query: SELECT * FROM DMisUserRestrictedAdmMriFac WHERE UserID = 'PPaul' and Source = 'STP'? Thanks.

Comment: The FacilityToRestrict can and often times does have multiple facility id's. @Michael the output for that shows 14 different facilities to be restricted. Both SignOnFacility and FacilitiesToRestric can have multiple values but I only care about the PSY values in each of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you want a `group by`.  Here is my guess as to what the logic is:

```
SELECT ppp.DeptID, mis.UserID, mis.[Name],
       COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN mis.ProviderID IS NOT NULL THEN 'YES' END), 'NO') as IsProv,
       COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN af.FacilityID <> 'PSY' THEN 'Not Restricted' END), 'Restricted') as SIgnOnFacility,
       COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN fr.FacilitiesRestrictedID <> 'PSY' THEN 'Not Restricted' END) as FacilityToRestrict,
        mis.Active
FROM . . .
GROUP BY ppp.DeptID, mis.UserID, mis.[Name], mis_Active;
```

Comment: I had to make a minor edit to that but it basically did the trick. Thanks! I always forget about coalesce and just don't use it as much as I probably should.